# teamtalk 4.6.3 linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Доброе время суток, используем teamtalk 4.6.3 и именно эту версию, установил на Linux так как переходим на нее, teamtalk скачал запускается нормально, к серверу подключается но вот проблема она невидит веб камеру, поставил skype для теста, skype видит камеру, куда копать?

Comment: Спросить у разрабов? Но я уверен, что раз на сайте анонсят 5-ю ветку - вам и там предложат поставить самый свежак.

Comment: Как бы это странно не звучало он разработчик сам не может ответить на этот вопрос)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С проблемой разобрался, нужно было подключить библиотеку libv4l